# Cannot add member in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-web-console

**What I have tried - Webconsole**

I have a problem with `openshift.com` - I am trying to add a member via the web console, and get an error every time.

**Result**

The error is:
`Could not update members.`

**What I have tried - rhc client**

When I try in the RHC client,

**Result**

> Adding 1 editor to domain ... There is no account with login xdc@mydomain.nu

How can I add a member?

Answer (score 1):

OK! So, the user that I want to add needs to have an existing openshift.com account.

Its about 'adding' a user, not creating a user.

Comment: Yes, they must have an existing account and give you their username.